# Variable value is not entering in the database table

Tags: wordpress

I am uploading enteries in wordpress database. And everything works fine. Only problem is one variable whose value is causing error.May be I am doing it wrong way.

```
$regcode = $code.000.$id;
```

Here `$code` contains integer value. `000` are static number and $id also contain integer value.

And then I am uploading data through insert query (by $wpdb) using `$regcode` (as mention above) variable. My all values are being inserted through variable. and all are inserting fine. Only this variable `$regcode` is causing trouble. Don't know why...

Comment: That's no wordpress related question, but i can see at least one error in your php scrip : change `$regcode = $code.000.$id;` to `$regcode = $code."000".$id;`

Comment: @Amin It is completely related to wordpress bcos I am using this code in my wordpress project and I am inserting value in wordpress database by using `$wpdb`. And about your answer I have tried this also earlier but its entering wrong value in my wordpress database table.

Comment: what do you say about my answer

Comment: Can you share more code please, and explain better what are you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use direct

```
    $regcode = $code."000".$id;
    or  use this way 
    $code = 10;
    $id = 23;
    $other = 45;
    $regcode = $code.$other.$id;
```

Comment: First way I have already tried. BUt your second way worked for me. Why it didnt come in my mind to use static number in variable also. Silly me!
Anyway Thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: I am glad to help you.@Rishabh